# ListView ContextAction not following layout

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Wondering if anyone else has run into the following issue.

I've got my `App.MainPage` wrapped in a navigation page

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
```

From `MyPage` I navigate to a user account page which is a `TabbedPage`

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyAccountTabbedPage());
```

and here's the xaml (pretty simple)

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <userAccount:SitesTab />
    <userAccount:ProjectsTab />
    <userAccount:SettingsTab />
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Now here's where it gets fun. From within my `SitesTab`, I need to show a `ListView` that contains `ContextActions`

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <ListView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Text="Do Stuff"/>
                        <MenuItem Text="Delete Stuff" IsDestructive="True"/>
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The issue I'm running up against is that the context action on Android doesn't cover/replace the NavigationBar, but rather pushes it down and screws everything up.

Before Context
[image]

After Context
[image]

So what's up here? Has anyone figured out a way around this? That context menu at the top of the page should cover over the NavigationBar instead of push everything down.

Comment: Can you please tell which version is your xamarin.forms? I'm currently working at a project which has Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193, it will cover the navigationbar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0hqT.png).

Comment: yes, I'm on the same version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out I needed the following in my app compat theme

```
<style name="myActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```